# Find XP client DNS settings in the registry?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-xp

I'm troubleshooting an issue and I need to find where client XP machines store their DNS information. I have a server with 3 NICs. 1 one of them has DNS information and two of them are in a private network not using DNS.

It appears to be NameServer entry under System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPip\parameters\Interfaces\guid. Anywhere else that info would be found?

Answer (score 1):

that's the place.

Answer (score 1):

That's the place, *unless* the DNS have been set by group policy.  In that case, it will be at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSclient or similar.  In fact, ipconfig will only show the addresses set at System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPip\parameters\Interfaces\guid., but any group policy DNS addresses will override them.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem continues check that default domain policy does not have dns servers setting enabled. its under Computer conf. > policies > admin templates > network > DNS Client